# Neovim block paste

Tags: vim, copy-paste, neovim

I've read some posts about copying and inserting via block/visual selection but I think something is wrong on my side. If I copy the word *hello*, then move the cursor onto the second `"` of the next line, block select all `"` and press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> in order to paste `hello` between the `"`, it pasts `hello` on each line but removes the second `"`.

origin:

```
"hello"
""
""
""
```

result:

```
"hello"
"hello
"hello
"hello
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing it the wrong way in visual block mode. If I understand you correctly, you want to insert here inside the quotes in line 2, 3, 4, right?

This is the correct way:

1. Copy the word `here`.
2. Go to first `"` in line 2 and press `Ctrl-V` to start visual block mode.
3. Press `2j` to also select line 3 and line 4.
4. Press `A` (note, this is capital A!)
5. Now we are in insert mode, press `Ctrl-R`, followed by `"`, then press `<ESC>` to leave insert mode.

After these steps, you should get what you want. For more info, open neovim and try read `:h v_b_A`.

Comment: Sorry, but I saw your post just yet. It really works but I think pasting from visual mode should have the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying to load neovim with no config file:

```
nvim -u NONE
```

The paste the text you want to change and test to se what happens.
In normal mode you can use: <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, whereas on insert mode you can try:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>

Comment: Same behavior without the configuration. It works as expected when I paste via `p` but not when pasting while have a block selection active.